# PHP won't recognise Mysql values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, fetch

```
    <?php include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages )

   $dbhost = 'name:3036';
   $dbuser = 'user';
   $dbpass = 'pass';

     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT PrimulContract, ExpiraContract, antrenor FROM users';
   mysql_select_db('vestiged_sala');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_close($conn);
?>




    <h4>Bun venit, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> !
    <hr>
    Abonamentul tau expira pe data de: <?php echo $row["ExpiraContract"]; ?> 
    <hr>
    Primul tau contract a fost facut pe data de : <?php echo $row["PrimulContract"];  ?>
    <hr>
    Pe data de <?php echo $row["antrenor"];  ?>  va trebui sa platesti instructorul !
    </h4>
```

It shows me blank. No text, no value.    In mysql, those 3 columns are varchar(50)  utf8_general_ci    data.

Can you help me? I can attach pictures if you want or provide more details about it.  Values from columns are text+number.  ex : ( 10 September 1956)

Comment: Where does your `$row` come from? In your code, you just execute the query with `mysql_query` but you don't get the results with `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)` or something..

Comment: @olibiaz  i have  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

Answer (score 2):

You have to fetch the data.  You're only collecting the result object:

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );  // This gives you the result, not a row
```

you need to fetch the row too:

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval);
```

Altho I'd strongly suggest moving up to mysqli_* functions rather than mysql_* functions, which are now deprecated.

Comment: Tried to do what you've said but it did not work. Still shows me blank.

Comment: @AlxTioltisan please read the doc http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php `mysql_fetch_assoc` return an array, so you have to loop through the result or use $row[0] to fetch the first result.

Comment: @olibiaz  I don't know what to do next here  $sql = "SELECT id as antrenor, PrimulContract, ExpiraContract
        FROM   users
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

Comment: Please read the doc, everything is explained very clearly in the examples. Its basic usage of php. And as @MikeMannakee said, please stop using `mysql_*` and give a look at `mysqli_*` or pdo.

Comment: @olibiaz  done. But it won't show with html code.  Look here a picture:  http://i.imgur.com/UBorPdE.png

Comment: @AlxTioltisan please update your question with the last code changes, then we wil be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this setlocale for date in your romanian format/ in other format

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ro_RO','Romanian'); 

echo strftime('%d %B %Y'); 
?>
```

Comment: I've edited and made it easier to understand. Can you help me now?